# Shrewsoft VPN connection disables internet on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: linux, vpn, tunnel, shrew

I am using the Shrewsoft VPN Client 2.2.1 on a Windows 7 machine, and on an Antergos (Arch) machine (installed via AUR), to establish a VPN connection to a customers intranet.

In my configuration under "Policy" I have turned off "Obtain Topology Automatically or Tunnel All", which allows me to configure the "Remote Network Resources". Here I have included all the IP ranges for which the VPN tunnel should be used. All other IPs (i.e. my intranet and the internet) are not supposed to use the tunnel.

On the Windows machine all is working as expected, whereas with the same configuration (I did export and import the settings from the client) under Linux I cannot access the internet/intranet while the VPN connection is up.